# Thickness to linear path

Tags: eyeshot

I can use some help to get thickness to a linear path solid. Creating the linear path model (in this case a metal flashing part) works as intended, but it has no thickness, which I like to have as well. I haven't so far found any useful hints on how to do this.

If I need to go another way, please advise.

Code part:

```
        var b1 = Math.Cos(Utility.DegToRad(45)) * 30;
        var h1 = Math.Tan(Utility.DegToRad(45)) * 30;

        var l1 = new LinearPath(Plane.YZ,
                        new Point2D(0, 0),
                        new Point2D(60, 0),
                        new Point2D(60, -120),
                        new Point2D(60 + b1, -120 - h1)
                    );
        var s1 = l1.ExtrudeAsSolid(new Vector3D(500, 0, 0), 1);

        s1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
        s1.ColorMethod = colorMethodType.byEntity;

        return s1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this instead:

```
var s1 = l1.ExtrudeAsSolid(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 0);
```

An extrusion vector of `1 unit` and a contour deviation of `zero` (`LinearPath` entity is not affected by deviation).